# How to hide Scala.JS types from JVM code?

Tags: scala, jvm, scala.js

I've been practicing leveraging as much JVM code as possible in Scala.JS in order to benefit from unit testing pure JVM logic, which is of course much faster. At some point though, you run into the issue where the function you'd like to implement in the JVM cannot be written without passing a JS object to it, even if you do not call any methods of this object (it's effectively an `AnyRef` for all intents and purposes).

For instance, in a React JS application, maybe you have some if/else logic for deciding which components to return from your JVM function in order for React to render. The components are just objects (`AnyRef`) as far as the JVM is concerned, but on the JS side they need to be upcasted back to component types:

I'm naively solving this using:

```scala
// convert to AnyRef at compile-time before passing to a JVM function:
type Jvm = AnyRef
def toJvm(elements: ReactElement*): Seq[Jvm] = elements : Seq[Jvm]
```

Then your JVM function decides which to render:

```scala
def whichToRender(isDayTime: Boolean, jvm: Seq[Jvm]): Seq[Jvm] = {
  if (isDayTime) {
    Seq(jvm.head)
  } else {
    Seq.empty[Jvm]
  }
}
```

But the downside is in order to convert back to JS, I must use `asInstanceOf`, which suffers a runtime cost:

```scala
def toJs(elements: Seq[Jvm]): Seq[ReactElement] = elements.asInstanceOf[Seq[ReactElement]]
```

So is there anyway to *hide* the underlying type of the React Component so that the JVM just *Sees* an Object but the underlying type is still recoverable, at compile-time to avoid runtime cost with type casting?

Comment: Why not just using generics instead of `AnyRef`?

Comment: There's no run-time cost to `asInstanceOf` once you're in fullLink mode. Also, there is no run-time cost to `asInstanceOf` when the target type is a JS type.

Comment: As for generics: why didn't I think of that! And @sjrd I've googled run-time but have come up empty handed, and what is "fullLink" mode? Is that the same as compiling with full optimization?

Comment: Yes, that's the same.